# AndroidSwipeLayout daimajia swipe layout disappearance immediately after swipe

Tags: android, swipe

I use Android swipe layout to with 2 child linear view. When i swipe, layout apprearance but it gone immediately. So what happend and how should i do to keep it not gone
Thanks

Comment: may be you should use swipe adapter , please provide piece of your code

Comment: thanks for reply, i check and it is only error on my device Sony E.

Comment: so how you fix it